# Printing Pydantic objects with Schema definitions included?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, schema, pydantic

I have a Pydantic model like

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class MainModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(
        "example",
        title='The name',
        description='The name assigned',
    )
    date: datetime = Field(
        datetime.now(),
        title='Date',
        description='The date of creation...',
    )
```

Pydantic makes it easy to print out the model schema with `MainModel.schema_json()`. Once I have initialized an object of MainModel, such as

```
example = MainModel(
    name="test",
    date=datetime.now()
)
```

I can print json/dict of `example`  by `example.dict()`, however, additional markup information like `title` and `description` aren't included. Is it possible to print these together, or will I need to do some sort of dict join between `MainModel.schema_json()` and `example.dict()`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any functionality like that in pydantic. But the dict join you have mentioned isn't too bad, e.g. like this:

```
def get_schema_and_data(instance):
    schema = instance.schema()
    for key, value in instance.dict().items():
        schema["properties"][key].update({"value": value})
    return schema


from pprint import pprint
pprint(get_schema_and_data(example))
```

Which results in:

```
{'properties': {'date': {'default': '2022-08-05T15:39:26.183702',
                         'description': 'The date of creation...',
                         'format': 'date-time',
                         'title': 'Date',
                         'type': 'string',
                         'value': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 5, 15, 39, 26, 185091)},
                'name': {'default': 'example',
                         'description': 'The name assigned',
                         'title': 'The name',
                         'type': 'string',
                         'value': 'test'}},
 'title': 'MainModel',
 'type': 'object'}
```

If you have a nested pydantic-object it gets more complicated, but at that point you could write a function that recursively traverses the schema-dict by stripping apart the layers in the example.dict()-dict and inserting the values.

Comment: I simplified the example, but you're right, a more complex dict could be recursively traversed. I suppose if Pydantic doesn't have anything built-in that this is the only way to do this, as I don't think there is any other way to add extra human-readable descriptors to fields?